# Pugjs can't create new mixin

Tags: keystonejs, pugjs

Hi folks so I just inherited this Keystonejs project and it is using pug. Everything's going good except I can't create new mixins.

Not only that but the old mixins(already defined) are working fine. I just can't create new mixins. If I do, I get this error:
Sorry an error occurred loading the page(500)
...
...
pug_mixins.info is not a function.
[image]

**index.pug**

```
extends ../layouts/default

block content
    +hero-header()
    +info()
```

**info.pug**

```
mixin info()
  .info
    .container
      .row
        .col-md-4
          .site-info__box
        .col-md-4
          .site-info__box
        .col-md-4
          .site-info__box
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:

If I move everything inside info.pug inside index.pug then it works.
Also, there's another mixin called hero-header. If I move everything from info.pug to hero-header.pug, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Welp nevermind. We have a master pug file which has all mixin files includes in it. Forgot to add info.pug inside it.